# Yii how to change the layouts directory location

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii

I want to know how to change the Yii layout directory from being default in the views folder. Here is the directory structure I am trying to create.

```
- themes
  - my theme
     - assets
     - images
     - layouts
        - main.php
        - column1.php
     - view -> symbolic link to /views

- views
  - all the views folders
```

I am using bootstrap throughout the entire application (my application has like 5 sub applications and some of them need to use a different theme) and all my themes and widgets are based on the bootstrap. All I will need to change is the layouts files.

Comment: `layoutPath` in config

Comment: If you're using theme, all you need to do is specify the theme's name in the config.

Comment: Sorry, i didnt clarify what i meant. I need to have only the layouts in the theme directory and the views should be symbolic link to a common views directory.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know exactly what you mean. Do you want to specific theme for each modules, controller, or also action in Yii ?

For example, if you want to config default theme for application ( all modules use it) 
In /protected/config/main.php , add :

> //config theme
>        'theme'=>'your_theme_name',
>   in array.

#### To config theme for a module

at init() method of Module default controller (Module class). add

> $this->layout='PATH_TO_THEME';

All controller of current Module will use that theme

#### Config layout for each controller and action

just include

for controller

> public $layout='layout_name';

for action

> $this->layout = 'layout_name';